# Can -Exclude and -Filter be used together?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script in which I am trying to get any LATEST csv file with Members in its name but not members AND `server[-1]` in its name

suppose server is an array holding servers in it. as an example, the file that should be left out would be `Members_server1.domain.com.csv`

```
Get-ChildItem "$csvLocation" -Filter '*Members*.csv' -Exclude "*Members_$($Server[-1])*.csv" | Where-Object {
                    $_.LastWriteTime.GetDateTimeFormats()[44] -eq $today
                } | Move-Item -Destination "$csvLocation\$($DBName)_Members_$($Server[-1]).csv" -Force
```

However, it doesn't look like exclude is working.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: in win7, ps5.1 the `-Exclude` & `-Include` parameters REQUIRE the use of `-Recurse`. [*sigh ...*] plus, they only refer to the file name, not the rest of the path.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey recurse worked!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey is there another way besides exclude? i have remove_item later on in my code and its now asking for confirmation because recurse is being used here.

Comment: the `-Exclude` & `-Include` parameters also do their filtering _in the cmdlet_, not at the source. that means you may not gain much speed from using them. i have not tested the speed difference, tho. try using a filtering stage in your pipeline - `Where-Object` if speed is not vastly important, `ForEach-Object` if you want more speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, `-Filter` and `-Exclude` can be used together**: `-Filter` filters at the source (asks the filesystem to perform the filtering, which is much faster than using `-Include`)) and `-Exclude` then makes PowerShell exclude matches.

**However, with `Get-ChildItem`, the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters - surprisingly - apply only directly to the leaf component of the (implied) `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` argument, not its *children*.**

While including `-Recurse` extends the inclusions / exclusions to the leaf components of all items *inside* the target folder, that obviously changes the behavior, given that not only the *immediate* children are processed.

**To process only the immediate children while applying inclusions / exclusions, use *wildcard expression `*`***:

```
Get-ChildItem $csvLocation/* -Filter *Members*.csv -Exclude "*Members_$($Server[-1])*.csv"
```

Note that `Get-Item` would equally work in this case, given that the aspect of *child*-item processing is achieved by the wildcard expression.

Comment: You can take off the doublequotes.

Comment: @js2010: I explicitly kept them, because with more complex value expressions it's better to use them routinely, so you don't have to remember when they're needed and when not, which isn't obvious; notably, if the subexpression (`$(...)`) comes _first_, you _must_ double-quote - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467.

Comment: this is great! i have a question: suppose the file i wanna exclude is called Members_server01.corp.domain.com  ... how can i wild card -exclude "*Members_com*.csv"? its not working like this  so what am i missing? of course, i can just do -exclude "*com*.csv" however, i am afraid in te future there may be files that will also have server names in it and it will end up confused. so i want both Members AND com wildcarded

Comment: @Cataster, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking, but in any event I encourage you to create a _new_ question. (Feel free to ping me here, once you have done so.)

Answer (score 1):

No, the filters don't seem to require include and exclude instead of filter.
Using Where-Object (?) you can specify the Name or FullName as part of the filter:

```
Get-ChildItem "$csvLocation" | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*Members*.csv' -and $_.Name -notlike "*Members_$($Server[-1])*.csv" -and $_.LastWriteTime.GetDateTimeFormats()[44] -eq $today } | Move-Item -Destination "$csvLocation\$($DBName)_Members_$($Server[-1]).csv" -Force
```

Or specify your own function

```
# setup example 
$today = [datetime]::Today.GetDateTimeFormats()[44]
$Server = @('server1')
$DBName = 'dbname'

echo test > 'members.csv'
echo test > 'members_server1.csv'

# functions
function FilterCsvFiles() {

    param(
        [System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]] $fileInfos
    )

    return $fileInfos | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*Members*.csv' -and $_.Name -notlike "*Members_$($Server[-1])*.csv" -and $_.LastWriteTime.GetDateTimeFormats()[44] -eq $today } 
}
# move items
Get-ChildItem "$csvLocation" | FilterCsvFiles | Move-Item -Destination "$csvLocation\$($DBName)_Members_$($Server[-1]).csv" -Force
```